# Why in HTML, only if no other semantic element is appropriate, can we use `span` and `div`?

Tags: html

I feel `<div>` and `<span>` are important but the rule or my reference notes say:

> When *only when no other HTML element is applicable* you can use `<span>` and `<div>`

What is the importance of this limitation?

Comment: *what is the important of this limitation* ? Means?

Comment: Mr. Alien, can't I use span and div freely without considering other suitable HTML elements.

Comment: Brad answer clears this doubt also.

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed as unclear... it's perfectly clear.

Comment: I am following the edx course HTML5 and CSS Fundamentals ,it says <div>, <span> are not semantic elements. You should only use <span> if no other semantic element is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chart from the [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) Web site may help you decide whether or not to use a `<div>`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`<span>` and `<div>` don't convey much meaning about the structure of the document.  They're more for utility.

Ideally, your HTML indicates something about document structure.  If you use `<h1>`, the browser knows, "this is a top level heading".  If you use `<p>`, the browser knows, "this is a paragraph".  This is important because not everything using your HTML is going to be a web browser your CSS rules.

Search engines, for example, use the structured document to determine what sort of content is on your page.  If it's all just text with no structure, the indexing algorithms can't know what's important and what isn't.

Comment: So far I understood ,It's a difference of using semantic and generic elements , always it is better to use semantic elements when compared to generic elements.

Comment: @Kuhan The main intent with the HTML is to specify the document's *content* structure. To that end, we have a whole variety of elements for common structures found in documents.  Realistically though, we sometimes need elements that are more for utility so that we can apply CSS and JS. The comment in your book is likely in response to a huge number of developers ignoring elements and just using `<div>` for everything rather than `<p>` or `<section>`, etc. It's not that one element is better than the other... it's that they have different purposes, and should be used for their intended purpose.